# Ontology development without following any specific Methodology

Tags: semantic-web, owl, ontology

I developed ontology by following these three steps:

1. Discovery of Ontologies for reuse
2. Selecting relevant reuse candidates
3. Customization/extending and integration of relevant ontologies

The end result I got is my ontology.

My questions is that there are many Ontology Development Methodologies I did not read about them but I created my ontology as I mentioned above.

Do I must need to follow a methodology?
Is the above mentioned way is the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This 20 min lecture](https://open.hpi.de/courses/semanticweb2014/items/4h7UDEJdmhfmpPZOMHPSGa) might be useful to get quickly aquanted with some considerations. It focuses mainly on the "Ontology development 101" methodology, which has the following steps:
determine scope -> consider reuse -> enumerate terms -> define classes -> define properties -> define constraints -> create instances

Having said that, I personally would not recommend following a particular methodology. Your personal "methodology" grows with experience. But knowing the existing methodologies could still be useful for adding consideration you might have not thought about.

Regarding the three steps, I would suggest a step in parallel to your second one. This is to select which ontologies to extend with yours, using `owl:imports`, and from which only too reuse some classes and properties.

Comment: I am going to write a paper on the my newly created ontology. What I got from your answer that it is not important to mention in my paper the name of specific Methodology that I have followed. Am I right? or do I must mentioned a methodology that I followed?

Comment: @Sultan, if you are writing a paper, then I would recommend you to include existing methodologies, if not as something you use, at least as something you have analysed and learned from, when going with your approach, even if that approach is not to follow them.